# Load custom dataset for Keras

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, keras

**MNIST Example:**

From [neon example] (http://neon.nervanasys.com/index.html/mnist.html): (similar to keras)

```
from neon.data import MNIST

 mnist = MNIST()

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test), nclass = mnist.load_data()
```

I want to obtain the same set of tuples for UCF_CC_50 dataset.

It's a dataset of 50 distinct images, of an aerial view of crowded areas.
I'm modifying [the segment behind this](http://neon.nervanasys.com/index.html/_modules/neon/data/image.html).

All the images are downloaded and contained in the folder 'Images'.

This is the **init**

```
def __init__(self, filename, url, size, path='.', subset_pct=100):
    # parameters to use in dataset config serialization
    super(Dataset, self).__init__(name=None)
    self.filename = filename
    self.url = url
    self.size = size
    self.path = path
    self.subset_pct = subset_pct
    self._data_dict = None
    if subset_pct != 100:
        # placeholder to use partial data set
        raise NotImplemented('subset percentage feature is not yet implemented')
```

This is what i have so far. I dont understand how to modify **init**.

```
class UCF(Dataset):
**def __init__(self, path='.', subset_pct=100, normalize=True):
    super(UCF, self).__init__('Images',
                                '//url',
                                15296311,
                                path=path,
                                subset_pct=subset_pct)**
    self.normalize = normalize

def load_data(self):
    filepath = self._valid_path_append(self.path, self.filename)

    with open(filepath, 'rb') as ucf:
        (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = pickle_load(ucf)
        X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 784)
        X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 784)

        if self.normalize:
            X_train = X_train / 255.
            X_test = X_test / 255.

    return (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test), 10

def gen_iterators(self):
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test), nclass = self.load_data()
    train = ArrayIterator(X_train,
                          y_train,
                          nclass=nclass,
                          lshape=(1, 28, 28),
                          name='train')
    val = ArrayIterator(X_test,
                        y_test,
                        nclass=nclass,
                        lshape=(1, 28, 28),
                        name='valid')
    self._data_dict = {'train': train,
                       'valid': val}
    return self._data_dict
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your question is likely to be down-voted, as it is too broad in nature, for which answers would be too large, or opinionated. You need to show your own effort and attempts at solving the problem, and then ask a specific question about a specific issue. For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: I have added more details. The dataset is available at https://github.com/acbarbosa/CrowdCounter/tree/master/data/UCFDataset

Comment: Please answer this instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505868/how-to-put-my-dataset-in-a-pkl-file-in-the-exact-format-and-data-structure-used

Comment: your question is hard to follow. Can you explain exactly what you want, without any code?