# How to put my dataset in a .pkl file in the exact format and data structure used in “mnist.pkl”?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pickle, hdf5, mnist

I'm trying to make a dataset of images in the same format as mnist.pkl

I have used https://github.com/dmitriy-serdyuk/cats_vs_dogs/blob/master/cats_vs_dogs/make_dataset.py as reference.

This is what i have so far

```
path = '/home/dell/thesis/neon/Images'

def PIL2array(img):
    return numpy.array(img.getdata(),
    numpy.uint8).reshape(img.size[1], img.size[0], 1)

def main():


fileList = [os.path.join(dirpath, f)
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path)
    for f in files if f.endswith('.jpg')]

print "Preparing your pickle files. Pls wait..."

t0 = time.time()
for file_ in fileList:
    print file_
    img = Image.open(file_)
    arr = PIL2array(img)
    cPickle.dump(arr,open(file_+"-prot0"+".pkl","wb"),protocol=0)

t1=time.time()
total = t1-t0
print "P(h)ickling execution time: %.2f sec" % total

# routine to recursively traverse a folder and save list of file names
pklList = [os.path.join(dirpath, f)
       for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path)
       for f in files if f.endswith('.pkl')]

#print "hi"
all_files = []
for file_ in pklList:
    all_files += [file_]
train_share = 0.6
valid_share = 0.2
seed = 1
n_train = int(len(all_files) * train_share)
n_valid = int(len(all_files) * valid_share)
rng = np.random.RandomState(seed)
rng.shuffle(all_files)
train = all_files[:n_train]
valid = all_files[n_train:(n_train + n_valid)]
test = all_files[(n_train + n_valid):]
save_path = os.path.join(dirpath, '../datasets.pkl')


with open(save_path, 'w') as fout:
    cPickle.dump((train, valid, test), fout)

filters = tables.Filters(complib='blosc', complevel=5)
hdf5_file = 'dataset.h5'
full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, hdf5_file)    
h5file = tables.open_file(full_path, mode='w',
                          title='pics',
                          filters=filters)
save_path = os.path.join(dirpath, '../datasets.pkl')
with open(save_path, 'r') as fin:
    files = cPickle.load(fin)

**for subfiles, subset in zip(files, ['train', 'valid', 'test']):
        group = h5file.create_group(h5file.root, subset, subset)
        X = h5file.create_vlarray(group, 'X', atom=tables.UInt8Atom(),
                                  title='Data values',
                                  expectedrows=len(subfiles),            f                                     filters=filters)
        y = h5file.create_carray(group, 'y', atom=tables.UInt8Atom(),
                                 title='Data targets',
                                 shape=(len(subfiles),), filters=filters)
        s = h5file.create_carray(group, 's', atom=tables.UInt32Atom(),
                                 title='Data shapes',
                           shape=(len(subfiles), 3), filters=filters)** 

for i, file in enumerate(subfiles):
        full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
        with open(full_path, 'r') as fin:
            image, label = cPickle.load(fin)    

        X.append(image.flatten())
        y[i] = label
        s[i] = np.array(image.shape)
        if i % 50 == 0:
            print '.. aggregated', i, 'from', subset
            h5file.flush()
    h5file.flush()
```

I have highlighted the section where Im facing problems. 
I keep getting the following error :

in main
    image, label = cPickle.load(fin)
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Did you dump a tuple or just the image ? If you dumped just the image then you're asking to pickle to load two elements while it only has one. Do  `image = cPickle.load(fin)` instead.

Comment: Your indentation appears to be off by a long shot as well, please correct this.

Comment: just do dataset = cPickle.load(fin) and the print the dataset shape to see what you did dump in the pickle file. the error indicates differences between the loaded data values and the variables

Comment: @Feras.. This is what i got when i printed image.shape
(432, 1024, 1)
(768, 1024, 1)
(680, 1024, 1)
(752, 1024, 1)
(768, 1024, 1)
(680, 1024, 1)
(768, 1024, 1)
(768, 1024, 1)
(480, 640, 1)
(1024, 1024, 1)
why did i not get 50 such pairs? Also, I think I do need image and label separately. Will this give me a data structure similar to mnist.pkl?

Comment: @Torxed.. i fixed the indentation

Comment: @MMF.. i tried that and then used print image.shape
output:
(432, 1024, 1)
(768, 1024, 1)
(680, 1024, 1)
(752, 1024, 1)
(768, 1024, 1)
(680, 1024, 1)
(768, 1024, 1)
(768, 1024, 1)
(480, 640, 1)
(1024, 1024, 1)
that doesnt seem right. Can u suggest something?

Comment: I need the tuple (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test), nclass
[X_train, Y_train = train_set
X_test, Y_test = valid_set]

Comment: you are printing the images not the dataset fetched by loading. I see that you have 10 different image size. How can you put them in an array this way?

Comment: @Feras I'm relatively new to this. How do you see that I have 10 different image sizes? 
If i change with open(save_path, 'w') as fout:
  cPickle.dump((train, valid, test), fout) to 
cPickle.dump((train, valid, test), fout, protocol=2)
will i be printing the dataset?

Comment: (432, 1024, 1) (768, 1024, 1). you don't see the difference here ?